# Exercise $2$ from chapter $5$ of Eisenbud's Geometry of Syzygies book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to solve exercise $2$ from chapter $5$ of Eisenbud's *The Geometry of Syzygies* book.The problem is as follows:

> Let $X$ be the union of two disjoint lines in $\mathbb P^3$, or a conic   contained in a plane in $\mathbb P^3$. Then $2=\mathrm{reg}(I_X) > \deg(X)-\mathrm{codim}(X)+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \in S=k[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ be a quadratic form. Then we have an isomorphism $(f) \cong S(-2)$ of graded $S$-modules, and so 
the regularity of $(f)$ is $2$ (irrespectively of whether the corresponding conic lies in a plane or not).

Now let $\ell_1,\ell_2$ be two disjoint lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$, and so the ideal
of their union is $I_{\ell_1} \cap I_{\ell_2}$. Now $I_{\ell_1} = (p_1,p_2)$, where $p_1,p_2$ are linear forms, and similarly $I_{\ell_2} = (q_1,q_2)$. Thinking of the two lines as $2$-dimensional subspaces in $k^4$, since they are disjoint, their sum must be $k^4$. This implies that their orthogonal complements are disjoint. This in turn implies that the linear forms $p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2$ are linearly independent and so by a change of coordinates we can assume that 
$I_{\ell_1} = (x_1,x_2)$ and $I_{\ell_2} = (x_3,x_4)$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are the indeterminates of the underlying polynomial ring. But then $I_{\ell_1} \cap I_{\ell_2} = I_{\ell_1} I_{\ell_2}$. Now, the regularity of the product of $d$ linear forms is $d$, by a result of Conca and Herzog, 2003. Consequently, the regularity of $I_{\ell_1} \cap I_{\ell_2}$ is $2$.

Regarding the inequality $\mathrm{reg}(I_X) > \deg(X)-\mathrm{codim}(X)+1$, note that the degree and the codimension of the two lines are each equal to $2$, while for the conic in a plane its degree is zero and its codimension is $1$.

Comment: Dear @Manos,Thank you! Please give me some time to digest your answer properly!

Comment: Dear Arpit by all means, and feel free to question any part you find unclear.

Comment: There is no need to invoke such a general result to find out the regularity of such a well known ideal like $(x_1,x_2)\cap(x_3,x_4)$. This follows easily from the exact sequence $0\to I\cap J\to I\oplus J\to I+J\to 0$.

Comment: Well, first we get that the regularity is at most 2. On the other side, it is greater than depth which is also 2. (Here I've used that the regularity index is 1; see Lemma 8 on page 83 from [these notes](http://www.emis.de/journals/RSMT/59-2/59.pdf).) We can also use the minimal graded free resolution of two skew lines in $\mathbb P^3$ which is more or less well known.